# Generating XSL to be applied to an XML file

Tags: javascript, css, xml, xslt

I have the following xml and modified an xsl file from a tutorial I followed to get started. The HTML that is returned contains the strings that I specify in the XSL, but the actual values from the XML file is not being populated.

The solution probably is something really simple, though at this point I need someone to point that out to me.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <chatTranscript startAt="2016-11-01T10:40:18Z" sessionId="0001JaC1DVH2001E">
    <newParty userId="0079581871120009" timeShift="0" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
        <userInfo personId="" userNick="John" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="0"/>
            <userData>
                <item key="EmailAddress">dskim@gmail.com</item>
                <item key="FirstName">John</item>
                <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item>
                <item key="LastName">Doe</item>
                <item key="MediaType">chat</item>
                <item key="TimeZone">120</item>
            </userData>
    </newParty>
    <message userId="0079581871120009" timeShift="15" visibility="ALL" eventId="2">
        <msgText msgType="text">ehfdfdfd</msgText></message>
        <newParty userId="00795818713E000C" timeShift="45" visibility="ALL" eventId="3"><userInfo personId="1" userNick="allendei" userType="AGENT" protocolType="BASIC" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
        </newParty><partyLeft userId="00795818713E000C" timeShift="50" visibility="ALL" eventId="4" askerId="00795818713E000C">
        <reason code="1">left with request to close if no agents</reason></partyLeft>
        <partyLeft userId="0079581871120009" timeShift="50" visibility="ALL" eventId="5" askerId="00795818713E000C">
            <reason code="4">removed by other party</reason>
        </partyLeft>
</chatTranscript>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    Email - <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/newParty/userData/item/EmailAddress"/>
    Fist Name: <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/newParty/FirstName"/>
    Identify Create Contact: <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/newParty/IdentifyCreateContact"/>
    Last Name: <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/newParty/LastName"/>
    Media Type: <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/newParty/MediaType"/>
    Message: <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/message/msgText"/>
    Reason for leaving: <xsl:value-of select="/chatTranscript/message/reason"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="newParty">
    - <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My aim is to obtain the text values for the fields I am trying to retrieve via XSL, and later on to retrieve some tag attributes as well.

Comment: For future posts, please keep in mind that XML and XSLT code are not considered code snippets on SO, they cannot be run here. Also, show the expected output. Thanks. Why did you tag this question with [tag:javascript]? Finally, your title is too general and does not say anything about your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some serious problems with your [XPath axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp). Using predicates(`[...]`) on the attributes of your elements will improve your code tremendously.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/chatTranscript/newParty[count(*) > 1]">
    <xsl:variable name="curParty" select="@userId" />
    Email - <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='EmailAddress']"/>
    Fist Name: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='FirstName']"/>
    Identify Create Contact: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='IdentifyCreateContact']"/>
    Last Name: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='LastName']"/>
    Media Type: <xsl:value-of select="userData/item[@key='MediaType']"/>
    Message: <xsl:value-of select="../message[@userId=$curParty]/msgText/text()"/>
    Reason for leaving: <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../partyLeft[@userId=$curParty])" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
Email - dskim@gmail.com
Fist Name: John
Identify Create Contact: 3
Last Name: Doe
Media Type: chat
Message: ehfdfdfd
Reason for leaving: removed by other party
```

Comment: Well according to me - who is ahem... the OP - the question was answered to my satisfaction. Although @MathiasMüller may have criticism against the formatting of my question - or that of the answer, the point is that we communicated sufficiently to get this done. Don't go bashing (and down voting) questions you cannot answer yourself.

Comment: @Harriet I did not bash at all; you must have misunderstood my (now deleted) comment. I made a factual statement about this question and answer and I suggested an improvement. zx485 has reacted to the comment in a polite way and has convinced me that my comment was partly inaccurate. But this does not detract from the fact that your question leaves a lot to the imagination of the reader (you do not show your expected output) and  that the title is overly general (it applies to every XSLT question on SO). I did not downvote your question.

Comment: I feel my question had a sufficient level of detail - I was trying to generate the required xsl for the xml and that is mentioned in the heading. Further more the heading and the body is supposed to go together forming a unity - introduction & more information. I feel I have achieved that. From my side I am very sceptic about your actions on this question. Randomly down voting people is a sport on SO - and to no benefit to those who really seek help. The only ones it seems to benefit are those who are at the top of the leaderboard.

Comment: @Harriet Getting criticized for what you write (and _only_ for what you write, not as a person per se) is an integral part of SO. Nobody likes to be criticized but overall, polite criticism leads to better questions and answers. Instead of attacking me personally (by saying I am not competent enough to answer your question) you should take such comments seriously and try to improve your question. If you seriously think anything I have done here (to help, of course) is inappropriate, please involve a moderator. Thanks!

Comment: I have involved a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your XPaths. First, you're missing the `userInfo` step, and second you need a predicate targeting an attribute.

Example, for e-mail address:

```
chatTranscript/newParty/userInfo/userData/item[@key="EmailAddress"]
```

There is no node named "EmailAddress". What there is, is an `item` node that has "EmailAddress" as the value of its @key attribute.

You have similar problems for your other XPaths. For example, for others you omit not only `userInfo` but `userData` also.